# Combine numpy arrays without losing repeated entries or entries not having an intersection with any other elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays and want to combine them on intersection of left index -1 and right index 0.

Given

```
 a = [
[1, 3],
[1, 9],
[2, 3],
[8, 9],
[8, 12]
]

and b = [
[3, 11],
[12, 13],
[12, 14],
[9, 11],
[9, 13],
[11, 14]
]
```

I desire to output a combined array

```
c = [
 [1, 3, 11],
 [1, 9, 11],
 [1, 9, 13],
 [2, 3, 11],
 [8, 9, 11],
 [8, 9, 13],
 [8, 12, 13],
 [8, 12, 14],
 NAN, 11, 14],
]
```

I tried using pandas with join, concat and merge and maybe I failed to pass the correct args but the output is not as I desire especially when `a` and `b` are completely disjoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)'s [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(a).merge(pd.DataFrame(b, columns=[1, 2]), on=1, how='outer').to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.,  3., 11.],
       [ 2.,  3., 11.],
       [ 1.,  9., 11.],
       [ 1.,  9., 13.],
       [ 8.,  9., 11.],
       [ 8.,  9., 13.],
       [ 8., 12., 13.],
       [ 8., 12., 14.],
       [nan, 11., 14.]])
```